# My Keras Conv1D model doesn't recognize a substring, and instead produces the same value for every input

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use a Con1D model to categorize DNA sequences, and as a starting point, I'd like to build a model that recognizes a specific sub-sequence in randomly generated DNA sequences.

**Test Data**

DNA consists of a sequence of one of 4 possible bases, A, T, G, and C.  I represent my DNA in "one hot" encoding -- a sequence consisting of a single base, A, would therefore be represented as `[1,0,0,0]` -- yielding a matrix with dimensions `SAMPLE_CT x SEQ_LENGTH x 4`.  For my test set, I generate a number of random sequences, and in a fraction of those sequences, I overwrite a portion of the sequence with a fixed "signal" sequence.  Sequences are scored based on whether the signal is present or not -- 1 for sequences containing the signal, 0 for sequences lacking it:

```
SIGNAL_LEN = 80
COUNT, LENGTH, FRAC_PRESENT = 20000, 5000, 0.3

X = np.zeros((COUNT, LENGTH, 4), dtype='uint8')
Y = np.zeros((COUNT,), dtype='float16')

# random sub-sequence:
signal = [random.choice([0,1,2,3]) for _ in range(SIGNAL_LEN)]

for seq_i in range(COUNT):
    for idx in range(LENGTH):
        # flip random index to 1
        X[ seq_i, idx, random.choice([0,1,2,3]) ] = 1

    if random.random() < FRAC_PRESENT:
        start_pos = random.randint(100, LENGTH - (100 + SIGNAL_LEN))
        for idx in range(SIGNAL_LEN):
            X[ seq_i, start_pos + idx, : ] = 0
            X[ seq_i, start_pos + idx, signal[idx] ] = 1

        # a score of 1.0 means present; 0.0 means absent
        Y[ seq_id ] = 1.0
```

**Keras Model**

I cribbed my model from [examples](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2483) I found online.  The output is the `score` described earlier, 1 for present and 0 for absent.

```
WINDOW = 20
sample_ct, width, depth = X.shape

# define base model
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add( Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=20,
                      input_shape=(width, depth),
                      kernel_initializer= 'uniform',
                      activation= 'relu') )
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4))
    model.add( Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=20) )
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4))
    model.add( Conv1D(1, kernel_size=20,
                      kernel_initializer= 'uniform',
                      activation= 'relu') )
    model.add( Flatten() )
    model.add( Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu') )
    model.add( Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output') )

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e04))

    model.summary()
    return model
```

The `model.summary` looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 4981, 256)         20736
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 4981, 256)         0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 1245, 256)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 1226, 128)         655488
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 1226, 128)         0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 306, 128)          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 287, 1)            2561
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 287)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               36864
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 1)                 129
=================================================================
Total params: 715,778
Trainable params: 715,778
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I then fit my model against half my test data, and predict the other half:

```
    from numpy.random import rand
    model = baseline_model()

    # initialize a random index
    idx = rand(sample_ct) > 0.5

    X_train, X_test = X[idx], X[~ idx]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[idx], Y[~ idx]

    model.fit( X_train,
              {'output': Y_train},
              epochs=3)

    pred = model.predict( X_test )
```

However, all my predictions are 0, with a MSE of 0.2994 after 3 epochs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your loss function should be binary cross entropy

Comment: @djk47463 - I switched to `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())` but still got the same output for each sample (0.299 this time around)

Comment: Did your predictions change though? you are fitting to  random data so I wouldn't expect to see "great" results.

Comment: @djk47463 - my prediction changed insofar as I got a different identical number for every sample, but it didn't perform any better.  Also, my data is identical each time, as I saved it to a .npy file and re-load the same data each time.  What do you mean by "random?"  This should be equivalent to starting w/ random bitmaps and pasting an identical image in half of them, then categorizing.  Shouldn't that work?